# how to get the filename of a thrown IOException in java?

Tags: java, ioexception

I have a try block which handles quite a few file opening/closing/reading/writing (more than one file).

It looks like:

```
try {
    // commands
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Error: " + e);
}
```

The main problem is that e.toString() does not contain information about the filename for which the exception was thrown, if there is an error.

I could check each read/write/open/close operation separately, and then know which file the error happens with, but that seems to defeat the purpose of having the elegant try-catch structure.

Is there any other way out? I just want to be able to print the file name for which e had the error in the try block.

EDIT: Maybe I should make it clear in which scenario this issue arises. This happens when I parse command-line arguments, input/output files, etc. I pass the file names to various functions and methods that can return with an IO error. It seems reasonable to require that I would have a generic way of handling any file problem by printing the error and the filename that had that error. I understand that IOException is more broad than handling IO with files, but surely it makes sense, given that IOException is a specialized exception class, to have a method that returns the IO source for which the error occurred.

Comment: well surely you have the `File` object in scope.

Comment: Isolate each operation within it's own try-catch block instead of trying to use a single catch all

Comment: @MadProgrammer That sounds more like the problem than the solution. If there was a single catch-all it would probably have the original `File` object still in scope. And I hope you mean to nest the try-catches, otherwise you've just recommended an anti-pattern.

Comment: @EJP From the sounds of question they have multiple files been read from and written to - but I could be wrong - I prefer a to isolate the responsibility where I can as it makes it easier to identify the problem and deal with it.  Whether they're nested or not would depend on the requirements, but normally, yes...

Comment: Perhaps they let the user choose the files and they're in a reasonable data structure that just so happens to be hard to read from. For instance, a tree: The IOException might've come from a file, but all you see is its grandparent directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't - as you know, `IOException` doesn't have information about the `File` that generated the exception. It's purpose it too general. If you roll your own, you can capture relevant information and catch your own exception instead.

In the various methods that handle your input, wrap the relevant section in try/catch blocks, catch the `IOException`, and throw your own with the additional data.

Here is a complete program that demonstrates the basic idea.

```
class FooException extends Exception { 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2816777468035627105L;
    private final String filename; 
    private final Throwable cause; 

    public FooException(String filename) { 
        this(filename, null); 
    }

    public FooException(String filename, Throwable cause) { 
        this.filename = filename; 
        this.cause = cause; 
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() { 
        return "Error reading file"; 
    }

    @Override
    public Throwable getCause() {
        return cause; 
    }

    public String getFilename() { 
        return filename; 
    }
}

public class Soj25375647 {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         try {
             throwsAnException();
             // Do other things that might throw my exception
         } catch (FooException e) { 
             System.err.printf("File: %s, error: %s, caused by %s%n", e.getFilename(), e, e.getCause());
         }
    }

    public static void throwsAnException() throws FooException { 
        try { 
            int x = 2 / 0;
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) { 
            throw new FooException("bob.file", e);   
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
File: bob.file, error: soj25375647.FooException: Error reading file, caused by java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

See Also [Exception-Handling Antipatterns](https://today.java.net/article/2006/04/04/exception-handling-antipatterns#creating-your-own-exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what's happening here. You probably have something like this:

```java
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < something; i++) {
        File f = getSomeFile(i);
        // Operations that might throw an IOException
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // handle
}
```

This is not a good idea; as you say you don't know the file that caused the error. Instead try something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < something; i++) {
    File f = getSomeFile(i);
    try {
        // Operations that might throw an IOException
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // handle
        break;
    }
}
```

This way, you still have `f` around when the error is thrown, but it also breaks out of the loop on an error just like the original code. Hope this helps!